# Replace null with value in mysql query with 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying replace null with 0 with following statement but returns no recrods instead of of catid supplied and 0.

```
select ifnull(count(*),0) as days, catid from mytable where Id=48 and catId=7 
group by mytable.catId;
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, COUNT(*) does never return NULL. It returns 0 if there is no record.

Answer (score 1):

`count(*)` never returns `NULL`, so you don't need any conditional logic:

```
select count(*) as days, catid
from mytable
where Id = 48 and catId = 7 
group by mytable.catId;
```

Perhaps your issue is that the query is returning no *rows*.  If so, you can leave out the `group by`.  Then the query will always return one row:

```
select count(*) as days, catid
from mytable
where Id = 48 and catId = 7 ;
```

Comment: query returns no rows but still I want to use group by because the catid will be provided in the query in loop some catid will have value.

Comment: @AyshaAbdulGafoor . . . The `group by` is unnecessary.  The `where` clause limits the output to one category.  If you always want one row, then leave out the `group by`.